# How do I import into a DataFrame from an html series (string)?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a piece of html code that contains a series. I have changed the string format to that required as a series to use pandas

```
s = {"2014-12-31":["price":385000,"count":3],"2013-12-31":["price":380000,"count":2],"2010-12-31":["price":400000,"count":2],"2019-10-31":["price":null,"count":null]}
```

How do I get this into a dataframe?

I have tried

```
df = pd.Series(s)
```

I even tried removing the "price": and "count": without success. Surely there must be a simple way to import a series from a string as if it were just defined as a series in the first place. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh, and I tried  df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(s)) too. This creates an incorrect dataframe.

Comment: Your `s` as shown is not a valid Python object. It looks like a nested `dict` but those square brackets shouldn’t be there, and neither should the `null`s. Please show the actual value of the variable `s`.

Comment: Please be more specific, and more careful, in your use of language. In Pandas, a `Series` is a sequence type, which makes expressions like _html series_ and _changed the string format to that required as a series_ confusing and ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

From this...

```
s = '{"2014-12-31":["price":385000,"count":3],"2013-12-31":["price":380000,"count":2],"2010-12-31":["price":400000,"count":2],"2019-10-31":["price":null,"count":null]}'
```

If I remove the column headers from the data

```
s = re.sub('"price":','',s)
s = re.sub('"count":','',s)
```

Then this works... (requires import json)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(s))
```

This is the resultant dataframe...

```
2014-12-31  2013-12-31  2010-12-31  2019-10-31
0   385000  380000  400000  None
1   3   2   2   None
```

And

```
df.T
```

gives this

```
    0   1
2014-12-31  385000  3
2013-12-31  380000  2
2010-12-31  400000  2
2019-10-31  None    None
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, is it? Why does your input string here not match the input in your question?

Comment: Yes, it is an answer although doesn't allow me to use column names which I believe is possible with pandas. 
The only change from the original question is the data is in a string so I added the surrounding quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

priceSeries = pd.Series([385000,380000,400000], index= ["2014-12-31","2013-12-31","2010-12-31"])
countSeries = pd.Series([3,2,2], index= ["2014-12-31","2013-12-31","2010-12-31"])

s = pd.DataFrame({"price": priceSeries,"count":countSeries})

s
```

Comment: This solution requires a complete reformatting of the original data :(   However, I have already posted a solution. I have the original field as a string - the containing quotes were missing.